# twilio device connect and reconnect

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I am trying to create a context api for twilio call connection. I would like to take help from twilio experts if I am doing it in correct way or not. In this context, What I am trying to do is connect twilio device and if the token expires then reconnect. But this way, the outgoing call is not working yet I could see the device is ready printed on my console. When I try to call, the `deviceInstance` state is shown null.

This is how I am doing

```
import { Device, Connection } from 'twilio-client';

import twilioReducers from './twilioReducers';

interface ITwilioContext {
  // device?: Device;
  setDeviceOnline?: () => void;
  state: InitialStateType;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>;
  handleDeviceOutgoing: (params: OutgoingProps) => void;
}

export const TwilioContext = createContext<ITwilioContext>({});

const TwilioProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [deviceInstance, setDeviceInstance] = useState<Device | null>(null);
  const [activeWorkspaceId] = useLocalStorage('activeWorkspaceId', null);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const [getVoiceToken, { data }] = useLazyQuery(VOICE_TOKEN, {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    onError: err => console.error(err),
  });

  // Commented inorder to prevent reintialization
  // const device = new Device();

  const initialState = { direction: '', showPhoneWidget: false };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(twilioReducers, initialState);


  /* event handlers for twilio device */
  const handleDeviceReady = (device: Device) => {
    console.log('Device ready');
    setDeviceInstance(device);
  };

  const handleDeviceOffline = async (device: Device) => {
    console.log('Device offline', device);
    if (device.token) {
      const twilioTokenDecoded = jwtDecode<JwtPayload>(device.token);
      if ((twilioTokenDecoded as any).exp <= Date.now() / 1000) {
        await getVoiceToken({});
        console.log('twilio new token data', data);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleDeviceError = (error: Connection.Error) => {
    console.log('Device error', error);
    if (TWILIO_ERRORS[error.code] !== undefined) {
      ToastMessage({
        content: t(TWILIO_ERRORS[error.code].errorKey, TWILIO_ERRORS[error.code].message),
        type: 'danger',
      });
    }
  };
  /* ----------------------------- */

  /* handle incoming calls */
  const handleDeviceIncoming = (connection: Connection) => {
    console.log('incoming', connection);
    dispatch({
      type: ACTIONS.INCOMING_CALL,
      data: connection,
    });
    connection.on(deviceEvent.CANCEL, () => {
      console.log('incoming-cancel');
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.INCOMING_CALL_CANCEL,
      });
    });

    connection.on(deviceEvent.DISCONNECT, () => {
      console.log('incoming-disconnect');
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.INCOMING_CALL_DISCONNECT,
      });
    });

    connection.on(deviceEvent.ACCEPT, () => {
      console.log('incoming-call-accept');
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.ANSWER_INCOMING_CALL,
      });
    });

    connection.on(deviceEvent.REJECT, () => {
      console.log('incoming-call-reject');
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.REJECT_INCOMING_CALL,
        updateConversationStatus: true,
      });
    });
    connection.on(deviceEvent.ERROR, (err: Connection.Error) => {
      console.log('Connection error occured', err);
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.INCOMING_CALL_ERROR,
        status: 'error',
      });
    });
  };
  /* ----------------------------- */

  /* handle outgoing calls */
  const handleDeviceOutgoing = (params: OutgoingProps) => {
    if (deviceInstance) {
      if (deviceInstance.isInitialized || deviceInstance.status() !== 'ready') {
        ToastMessage({ content: t('error.deviceSetup', 'Device is offline.'), type: 'danger' });
        return;
      }
      const connection = deviceInstance.connect(params); // copied from premvp
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONS.OUTGOING_CALL_INITIATED,
        data: connection,
        status: 'connecting',
        channelId: params?.channel_sid,
      });
      connection.on(deviceEvent.RINGING, (val: boolean) => {
        if (val) {
          dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.OUTGOING_CALL_RINGING,
          });
        }
      });

      connection.on(deviceEvent.CANCEL, () => {
        console.log('Connection cancelled');
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.OUTGOING_CALL_DISCONNECT,
        });
      });

      connection.on(deviceEvent.DISCONNECT, (conn: Connection) => {
        // handle user hungup
        console.log('Connection disconnected', conn);
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.OUTGOING_CALL_DISCONNECT,
        });
      });

      connection.on(deviceEvent.ACCEPT, (conn: Connection) => {
        console.log('Connected to the user', conn); // handle user answercall
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.OUTGOING_CALL_ANSWERED,
        });
      });

      connection.on(deviceEvent.REJECT, (conn: Connection) => {
        console.log('Rejected', conn); // handle user answercall
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.REJECT_OUTGOING_CALL,
        });
      });

      connection.on(deviceEvent.ERROR, (err: Connection.Error) => {
        console.log('Connection error occured', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No Device Instance exist');
    }
  };
  /* ----------------------------- */

  useEffect(() => {
    const device = new Device();
    console.log('device', device, data);
    if (data?.getVoiceToken?.data?.voiceToken) {
      device.setup(data?.getVoiceToken?.data?.voiceToken, deviceConfig);
      device.on(deviceEvent.READY, handleDeviceReady);
      device.on(deviceEvent.OFFLINE, handleDeviceOffline);
      device.on(deviceEvent.ERROR, handleDeviceError);
      device.on(deviceEvent.INCOMING, handleDeviceIncoming);
    }
    return () => {
      device.destroy();
      setDeviceInstance(null);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [data?.getVoiceToken?.data?.voiceToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeWorkspaceId !== '') {
      getVoiceToken({});
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [activeWorkspaceId]);

  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      state,
      dispatch,
      deviceInstance,
      handleDeviceOutgoing,
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [state]);

  return <TwilioContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</TwilioContext.Provider>;
};

export default TwilioProvider;
```

Comment: I've not done this within a context provider before. Can you explain a bit more where you find the `deviceInstance` exists and where it doesn't? Are you able to log and see the `useEffect` functions running and setting up the device? You are logging the device events, what logs do you see?

Comment: this one is working fine now. Perhaps, I did mistake in some consumer component which in turn created the above issue. I apologize the mistake is not in the code which I have shown in question. Thank you @philnash for your consideration.

Comment: Oh, well that's good news!

Comment: @philnash you are a twilio expert so if it's legal to ask different question here then can you give some feedback on the above code which is for handling incoming and outgoing call and renew the token if twilio token expires?

Comment: You appear to have implemented handlers for all the events and they look reasonable to me. I'm not sure how this works within a React context, but if it is working for you then I can't find anything definitely wrong with it. If you are having trouble with a specific feature, I'd recommend you ask a new question here and point at the relevant code and describe what is going on.

Comment: Thank you @philnash for your feedback. Sure, I will ask a new question if I get a problem and could not solve it. We are building big application totally relying on twilio.

Comment: Awesome, well I am here to help if you get stuck!

Comment: Sure, I will. Thank you for your kind and helping nature.